# How do I fix the error I get when executing pip in Spyder 5.0.3

Tags: pip, ipython, spyder

I am getting an error when trying to run pip through Spyder 5.0.3

I have recently installed Spyder 5.0.3 on my machine from https://www.spyder-ide.org/

When I attempt to exectute "pip --version" on IPython in Spyder I get the following error message:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I fix this so I can run pip in IPython Spyder?

Answer (score 2):

The standalone installer for Windows available in the Spyder website doesn't have pip in it. If you want to use or install a specific package outside of the ones that are shipped with the standalone installer you will need to go with the modular approach to use Spyder (create an environment and select his python executable as the interpreter that Spyder will use).

For that you will need to:

- Install a python distribution as for example miniforge: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/tree/4.10.1-3#download
- Create a new python environment, install `spyder-kernels` and the packages you want to use in it.
- Set the Spyder interpreter preference to point to the environment created.

The Spyder GitHub wiki has a page that explains the process to setup some of this elements: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach

Comment: Thankyou, this solved the problem. I wasn't aware that the Spyder standalone doesn't have pip in it.

Comment: This sounds a very difficult solution , so if I don't install anaconda, I will need miniconda and Spyder ?

Comment: The explained/recommended approach with the installer is that but in the end you could use any other way to handle your environments (although yes you will need Spyder as a standalone application and then something else to handle the environments). Maybe in the future a way to handle basic environments from the standalone Spyder application could be a good idea